# Active Sessions won't close on windows server 2012 which causes the oracle server to crash

Tags: oracle, iis-8, windows-server-2012

We've updated our OS from windows server 2003 to 2012 and we're having problems with our  sessions. They simply don't die even though they all have the neccesary code line (and they did die properly on the 2003, ii6). When about 3000 sessions accumulate, the IIS8 crashes.

Restarting the IIS clears all the open accumulated sessions but this should be done every hour or so, which is not realistic and damages the services we provide.

We use classic ASP, 11gR2 Oracle client.

Comment: What are COM sessions? Do you have any simple code to illustrate the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry. "Com sessions" isn't the right way to describe it. I meant inactive sessions (that were created by a COM, but that's not crucial).

Comment: COM doesn't create "sessions" - it creates "objects".

Comment: Note that I'm not nitpicking for the sake of nitpicking, the deal is that your question doesn't make much sense with current wording and is unlikely to be answerable.

Comment: thanks. Disregard the word "com". My server accumulates inactive sessions even long after they were suppose to die.

Comment: Okay, then it can be a platform bug or your code bug that deals with the sessions. Nothing more useful can be said without seeing at least some minimum of the code.